# Does Deus Ex: Human Revolution require Steam to play on PC?

Tags: steam, deus-ex-human-revolution

I want to know if PC copies of **Deus Ex: Human Revolution** bought at retail can (or must) be activated on Steam to run?

I've seen information indicating the game uses Steamworks (implying it can or must be Steam activated), but then conflicting information to indicate the *Steam version* of the game uses Steamworks (implying non-steam version cannot be activated).

If anyone can find an official source that would be most helpful.

Comment: Yes, non-Steam would be referring to the Onlive version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every version of Deus Ex: Human Revolution is going to require Steam to play. DE:HR is in the [Steamworks RETAIL SUPPORT](http://steampowered.com/steamworks/retailsupport.php) list. And there is a [offical statement](http://www.deusexcentral.com/news/2011/05/0602/):

> LONDON, UK - DEUS EX: HUMAN REVOLUTION™ is making a triumphant return
>   to its franchise PC roots, with digital availability on Steam®, the
>   leading online platform for PC games and digital entertainment, as
>   well as in boxed copy form at retailers worldwide at launch in August
>   2011. Eidos-Montreal has chosen this agreement with Steam because of its esteemed capability for an enhanced experience for the PC gamer,
>   with boosted functionality and easy accessibility.
>
> DEUS EX: HUMAN REVOLUTION will support a host of Steamworks® features
>   such as auto-updating, Steam Achievements and Steam Cloud support.
>   Available in the standard version and the robust Augmented Edition on
>   Steam, gamers will be able to enjoy the Deus Ex experience of their
>   choice. The Augmented Edition boasts a digital 40-page art book, a
>   “making of” special, trailers, animated storyboard of the CGI trailer,
>   motion graphic novel, soundtrack, and a free download of the Deus Ex
>   Game of the Year Edition.
>
> Telling the story of Adam Jensen, a man cybernetically augmented
>   against his choice who finds himself in the middle of a global
>   conspiracy to which he holds the key, DEUS EX: HUMAN REVOLUTION is set
>   in a near-future world where humanity is at a turning point. By
>   offering players the chance to play the game in multiple and vastly
>   different ways, DEUS EX: HUMAN REVOLUTION challenges the foundations
>   of gaming and provides an immersive experience where every choice has
>   a lasting consequence.
>
> DEUS EX: HUMAN REVOLUTION is available now for pre-order on Steam at
>   special limited-time pricing of £29.99 (standard version) and £39.99
>   (Augmented Edition), for release on August 26 in Europe.
>
> This title is not yet rated. For more information about DEUS EX: HUMAN
>   REVOLUTION visit www.deusex.com and join the human revolution at
>   http://www.facebook.com/DeusEx.

Answer (score 1):

Steamworks is included for any PC version, whether purchased through a download service (like... er, Steam) or purchased in a box from a store. While Portal 2 was able to make use of Steam on the PS3, preliminary reports are suggesting that the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions of the game do *not* use Steamworks, presumably because the game is exclusively single-player.

Answer (score 1):

The standard PC edition came with an OnLive code you could activate to use that instead of Steam (at least in the NA region). This means it isn't really *necessary* to activate the game on Steam to play it - you can use OnLive instead.